# Function to convert an array object and its rewriting

Tags: javascript

When choosing a currency to convert all the price products according to what they choose and then defend the change in the page

I want when I select a coin to convert the sum of all the products in the chunk and then to show the sum of each product

The function must be written in javascript vanilla without jquery

This is the list of objects

```
let productsList = [
  {
    imageURL: "https://s12emagst.akamaized.net/products/8096/8095064/images/res_689070343515d1e2bcd294526b17f3c8_200x200_gnvo.jpg",
    discount: "-15%",
    name: "Monitor LFD PHILIPS 4k",
    brand: "philips",
    colors: "black",
    stoc: "out stoc",
    review: "",
    type: "monitor",
    price: 70000
  },
  {
    imageURL: "https://s12emagst.akamaized.net/products/22044/22043004/images/res_b6ecd7bc761b9d80fcefe28923b1b756_200x200_59vo.jpg",
    discount: "",
    name: "Monitor LED Dell Curbat 4k",
    brand: "dell",
    colors: "black",
    stoc: "on stoc",
    review: "",
    type: "monitor",
    price: 49000
  }];
```

This is the function that creates the cards

```
function createCard(product) {
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.className = 'card';

  let box_d = document.createElement('div');
  box_d.className = 'box-d';
  box_d.innerHTML = product.discount;
  if (product.discount !== "") {
    card.appendChild(box_d);
  }

  let box_h = document.createElement('div');
  box_h.className = 'box-h';
  box_h.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-2x fa-heart" onclick="heartSlide()"></i>';
  card.appendChild(box_h);

  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.className = 'card-img';
  image.src = product.imageURL;
  card.appendChild(image);

  let review = document.createElement('div');
  review.className = 'p-info';
  review.innerHTML = 'Review: <span class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>';
  card.appendChild(review);

  let name = document.createElement('div');
  name.className = 'p-info';
  name.innerHTML = product.name;
  card.appendChild(name);

  let stoc = document.createElement('div');
  stoc.className = 'p-info';
  stoc.innerHTML = `Stoc: ${product.stoc}`;
  card.appendChild(stoc);

  let price = document.createElement('div');
  price.className = 'p-info';
  price.innerHTML = `Price: ${product.price} RON`;
  card.appendChild(price);

  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = 'add-btn';
  button.innerHTML = 'Add to cart <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart an"></i>';
  card.appendChild(button);

  return card;
}
productsList.forEach(product => document.body.append(createCard(product)));
```

Comment: Not able to understand what exactly you want.

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multiplier object where you add the supported currency and the multiplier.

For ex, 
If your base currency is `RON` then:

```
const curMap = {
  RON: 1,
  USD: 0.24
}
function createCard(product, currency) {
   ...
   let price = document.createElement('div');
   price.className = 'p-info';
   price.innerHTML = `Price: ${product.price*curMap[currency]} ${currency}`;
   card.appendChild(price);
   ...
}
```

Now you can just clear the product section and re-generate the cards.

```
productsList.forEach(product => document.body.append(createCard(product, "RON")))
```

Comment: I tried what you said but I get the Price: NaN undefined

Comment: Are you sending the currency? You are not. Check the edited answer.